# Java snippet implementing `bottomUp` for a linked stack

Tags: java, data-structures

I found this code example from a courseware that implements `bottomUp` for a linked stack class:

> ```java
> public class LinkedStack<E> implements Stack<E> {
>     private int size;
>     private Node<E> top;
>
>     static class Node<E> {
>         E elem;
>         Node<E> next;
>
>         Node(E elem, Node<E> node) {
>             this.elem = elem;
>             this.next = node;
>         }
>     }
>  // omitted methods such as top()
>
>     public void bottomsUp() {
>         if (this.size < 2){
>             return;}
>         // move to the second last node in the stack
>         Node<E> n = this.top;
>         for (int i = 0; i < this.size - 2; i++){
>             n = n.next;}
>         // n.next is the current bottom node
>         // attach it to the top node and make it the new top node
>         Node<E> newTop = n.next;
>         newTop.next = this.top;
>         this.top = newTop;
>         // n is the new bottom node; sever its next link
>         n.next = null;
>     }
> }
> ```

My question:

The `for` loop basically sets `n` to the second last node of `this`.
For example, for the linked stack `1->2->3->4->null`, the initial value of `n` is `3`.
But the snippet that follows confuses me:

It creates a new top `4->1`, with value 4 and linked to the current top. So now the stack is

```
4     top 
1
2
3   the second last node, which is also the equal to `n` at this point
4   bottom
null
```

Then, it sets the `n.next`, in this case the bottom node, which has value 4, as `null`. So now the stack is

```
4     top 
1
2
3   the second last node, which is also the equal to `n` at this point
null   bottom
null
```

So the bottom becomes `null`, not `3`. And this is the end of the method `bottomUp`.

- Why does this method leave two nulls in the bottom?
- Practically, how do i "find" a node which I can start from when using this `Stack` class?

I will really appreciate if anyone can this explain this snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It creates a new top 4->1, with value 4 and linked to the current top.

That is where you went wrong. It doesn't create a **new** top. The assignment `Node<E> newTop = n.next;` doesn't call the `Node` constructor; it merely assigns a reference to `newTop`, so that now both `newTop` and `n.next` are references to the *same* node. The number of nodes doesn't increase:

```
 top                              n             newTop
  ↓                               ↓               ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ elem: 1   │   │ elem: 2   │   │ elem: 3   │   │ elem: 4   │
│ next: ──────► │ next: ──────► │ next: ──────► │ next: null│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

The next statement `newTop.next = this.top;` will replace the last `null` with a reference to the current top, temporarily creating a circular list (without any `null`):

```
     top                              n             newTop
      ↓                               ↓               ↓
    ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
    │ elem: 1   │   │ elem: 2   │   │ elem: 3   │   │ elem: 4   │
┌─► │ next: ──────► │ next: ──────► │ next: ──────► │ next: ─┐  │
│   └───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘   └────────│──┘
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The next assignment sets the `top` to what the `newTop` references, i.e. `this.top = newTop;`:

```
                                      n              top newTop
                                      ↓               ↓   ↓
    ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
    │ elem: 1   │   │ elem: 2   │   │ elem: 3   │   │ elem: 4   │
┌─► │ next: ──────► │ next: ──────► │ next: ──────► │ next: ─┐  │
│   └───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘   └────────│──┘
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

We now need to break the circle again, by placing a `null` somewhere, which is what `n.next = null;` achieves. To quote what you wrote:

> Then, it sets the `n.next`, in this case the bottom node, which has value 4, as `null`.

In other words, it sets the `next` field of the `n` node to `null`, and we get this:

```
                                      n              top newTop
                                      ↓               ↓   ↓
    ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
    │ elem: 1   │   │ elem: 2   │   │ elem: 3   │   │ elem: 4   │
┌─► │ next: ──────► │ next: ──────► │ next: null│   │ next: ─┐  │
│   └───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘   └────────│──┘
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

And all is done now. At the end of the function the local variables `newTop` and `n` are discarded, and the above figure is then really the same as this one:

```
 top
  ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ elem: 4   │   │ elem: 1   │   │ elem: 2   │   │ elem: 3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next: ──────► │ next: ──────► │ next: null│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

Now to your questions:

> Why does this method leave two nulls in the bottom?

I hope the above illustrates that it doesn't do that.

> Practically, how do i "find" a node which I can start from when using this Stack class?

This is done by the `for` loop. For instance, if instead of finding the one-but-last node, you need to find a node by its *value*, then make that a condition to break out of the loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I still have a question: does change of the reference change the object itself? when the code redefined `newTop.next`, did it at the same redefine `n.next.next` ?  Is this a general situation in Java, that if I assign `x = y`, then `x` is actually not a copy of `y` named `x` but a same object as `y`, i.e. whatever I did to `x` I automatically did the same to `y`?

Comment: Yes, this is a general principle in Java. If you assign an object, no new object is created.

Comment: This behaviour of Java really confused me a lot, as I came from languages without such a mechanism. Anyway, thank you very for your help.

Comment: Just don't think as Java objects as structs, but as pointers to structs, without any possibility to have a variable equate the struct itself, as would be possible in C. The dot in `n.next` should be seen as writing `n->next` in C syntax.